# H2 in-memory database with Postgres. Some Tables not found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2

I'm trying to config a juinit testing with h2 in-memoty Db.

This is my config:

```
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
  datasource:
    jdbcUrl: jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=PostgreSQL;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
    username: sa
    password: sa
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
```

when I run my tests I notice that some tables are not found(or not accessible). while the logs show that the tables were created: `Hibernate: create table some_table`.
Some tests fails with `Table "some_table" not found;`

My table Entity looks like:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "some_table")
public class SomeTable extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {
  @Column(name = "col_name")
  private String colName;
}
```

And jpa like this

```
public interface SomeTableRepository extends JpaRepository<SomeTable, Long> {
  Optional<SomeTable> findFirstBySomeCol(SomeCol someCol);
}
```

p.s. Jpa repositories works fine with usual DB connection.
If smth not clear, feel free to ask me questions

Comment: `DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE` is for H2 1.4.197 and older versions, in 1.4.198 and newer versions PostgreSQL compatibility mode should be used together with `DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE`: https://h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility